# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: disconnected: not connected to DevTools error using ChromeDriver Chrome using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, cucumber-jvm

I am seeing below error and browser got disconnected between. Its happening only for chrome. Selenium version I am using is:

```
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
<version>3.141.59</version>
```

Error stack trace:

```
[1579632222.785][SEVERE]: Unable to receive message from renderer
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: disconnected: not connected to DevTools
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.117)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'MBP15-PBJGH8.8x8.com', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:1846:114d:10a6:bf26%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.6', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 79.0.3945.117, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 78.0.3904.70 (edb9c9f3de024..., userDataDir: /var/folders/mz/2_llwtkx31d...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:54446}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 3577826ba5ac2d089a34e17f9aa987c9
```

Comment: Please remember to mark the answer that solves your issue. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: disconnected: not connected to DevTools
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.117)
.
.
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 79.0.3945.117, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 78.0.3904.70 (edb9c9f3de024..., userDataDir: /var/folders/mz/2_llwtkx31d...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:54446}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **Browsing Context** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=78.0*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=78.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/78.0.3904.70/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v78**

- You are using *chrome=79.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v79.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/79.0.3945.36/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome 79**

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver v78.0* and the *Chrome Browser v79.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v79.0.3945.36](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=79.0.3945.36/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 79.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v79.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/79.0.3945.36/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same type of error. This error appears even with the latest ChromeDriver for Chrome browser (118.0). Local PC works fine, remote or virtual works fine until I disconnect from the machine. I think this error has to do with the user session on the remote machine, since when disconnected or screen saver kicks in the ChromeDriver loses its connection with the browser instance it controls.

The fix that worked for me: switch the sleep and screen mode to never (if Windows box).

Comment: Could you elaborate? I get it (with python though) even if my sleep timer on windows is set to never. My screen gets turned off after a while though, however the selenium jobs keep on being processed. I get the error only when I leave idle for it for a while.