# Get this warning with latest Chromedriver: Unable to evaluate script: disconnected: not connected to DevTools . How to resolve this?

Tags: selenium, console, warnings, devtools, logentries

I get this warning in eclipse : Unable to evaluate script: disconnected: not connected to DevTools when running cucumber selenium script.
[image of the warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agiIe.png)

I am using the latest Chrome driver version. Since this issue, the following code does not give the out put.

```
enter code here public boolean isMixedContentWarningsAppearing() {
    String warning = null;
    boolean result = true;

    try {
        LogEntries entry = driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER);

        List<org.openqa.selenium.logging.LogEntry> logs = entry.getAll();

        for (org.openqa.selenium.logging.LogEntry e : logs) {
            if (e.toString().contains("Accessing")) {

                System.out.println("..... warnings...." + e);
                warning = e.toString();
                // Reporter.addStepLog(warning);
            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    if (warning == null) {
        result = false;
        Reporter.addStepLog("No MixedContent warnings");
    } else {
        result = true;
        Reporter.addStepLog("The application contains Mixed Contents");
    }

    return result;
}
```

can anybody help me to run this code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: disconnected: not connected to DevTools error using ChromeDriver Chrome using Selenium and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59847431/org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-disconnected-not-connected-to-devtools)

Comment: No I am using the latest chromedriver: ChromeDriver 87.0.4280.88. is this a version mismatch?

Comment: What version of Chrome Browser are you using? Is it compatible with your ChromeDriver version?

Comment: Yes I am using the same version for both webdriver and browser . it is 87.0.4280.88. this, List<org.openqa.selenium.logging.LogEntry> logs = entry.getAll(); returns a empty list now. But it gave all the warnings before.  is this happening due to this devtool disconnection?