# WebDriverException: Message: disconnected: not connected to DevTools (failed to check if window was closed: disconnected: not connected to DevTools)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I put my system to sleep and resume it, I get the below error message.

> WebDriverException: Message: disconnected: not connected to DevTools
> (failed to check if window was closed: disconnected: not connected to DevTools)
> (Session info: chrome=113.0.5672.77)

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me too when I put my pc to sleep, I think what it means is that the session webdriver created has ended or it could not find the session even if the window (session) is still open. I found a similar question on SO here [org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: disconnected: not connected to DevTools error using ChromeDriver Chrome using Selenium and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59847431/org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-disconnected-not-connected-to-devtools)
it might help

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35613842)